# Flexbox float div to right

Tags: html, css

I need the yellow div to float beside the the purple square. Orange on top, pink on the bottom and yellow to the left of the square. It worked when I took off the `flex-wrap:wrap;` from the right div but then all three divs went to the left. Is there anyway to just have the yellow div float to the right of the purple square to take up the remainder of the green area while the other two stay in their current spots?

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  background-color:pink;
  height:91%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

#right{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right>* {
        flex: 1;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:calc(80vh - 25px);
  background-color:purple;
  margin-left:0;
}
#logo:before {
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#rightsidetop{
  background-color:orange;
}

#rightsideright{
  background-color:yellow;
}

#rightsidebottom{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightsidetop"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="rightsideright"></div>
    <div id="rightsidebottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as intended.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  background-color:pink;
  height:91%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

#right{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right>* {
        flex: 1;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:calc(80vh - 25px);
  background-color:purple;
}
#logo:before {
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#rightsidetop{
  background-color:orange;
}

#rightsideright{
  background-color:yellow;
  flex: 1;
}

#rightsidebottom{
  background-color:pink;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightsidetop"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="rightsideright"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidebottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** To make this answer a bit more universal, here is how the principle works: if you want div A to grow up to a max size, and div B to fill the remaining space, you have to make sure that:

- The container is `display: flex`
- A has `width: 100%` and has a `max-width`
- B has `flex: 1`

Take note that if A would have `flex: 1` as well, its greedy `100%` would be overruled by the more generous flexing rule. Therefore the most minimal working example is:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.up-to-max {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.filler {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="up-to-max">A</div>
  <div class="filler">B</div>
</div>
```

*(Watch in full page to resize the window)*

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your html a bit and to adapt the css.
On a side note, you shouldn't use that much id, use classes.
Also, use flex-basis to give flex children a width.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  background-color:pink;
  height:91%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

#right{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right>*,
#right>* > *{
        flex: 1;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:calc(80vh - 25px);
  background-color:purple;
  margin-left:0;
}
#logo:before {
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#rightsidetop{
  background-color:orange;
}

#rightsideright{
  background-color:yellow;
}

#rightsidebottom{
  background-color:pink;
}


.wrapper {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightsidetop"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="rightsideright"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidebottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thats close but It stops the purple div from expanding. Paste the code into a browser and youll see the issue. Ill try modifying what you suggested to see if I can get it to work

Comment: Try pasting my original code into a browser to see how the yellow (currently green) should work with screen resizing.